# Using google map place api service

Tags: c#, asp.net, google-maps

I want to use *Google Map Place API* service in `ASP.NET` application.
How do I use it and what are the requirements for it ?

```
var request = {
            location: map1.getCenter(),
            radius: '20',
            query: 'Roberstenstrasse 80, 4310, Rheinfelden, Switzerland'
        };

        var service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(map1);
        service.textSearch(request, callback);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can refer to this links and try google map api in asp.net

http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Google-Maps-GeoLocation-API-Example.aspx

http://www.aspdotnet-suresh.com/2013/01/generate-google-maps-api-key-for.html

there are nothing such requirement except a google file

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
```